# How to mock variables in try-with-resource blocks

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mocking, mockito

I am currently using `junit-4.12` along with `mockito-1.10`. I am trying to inject mocks into try-with-resource block such as

```
try (InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream("inputFile.txt") {
    ...
}
```

Is there a way in which I can inject mock for `inputStream`? I have tried declaring `inputStream` outside of `try` block as below:

```
InputStream inputStream;
try (inputStream = new FileInputStream("inputFile.txt") {
    ...
}
```

However, Java does not like this and throws error.

I am open to using any other library if I must, any help will be appreciated!

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do it:

using [PowerMockito](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.powermock/powermock-api-mockito)

```
import static org.powermock.api.mockito.PowerMockito.whenNew;

 // ...
InputStream inputStreamMock = mock(InputStream.class);
whenNew(FileInputStream.class).withArguments("inputFile.txt").thenReturn(inputStreamMock);
```